# Inconsistent Javascript sorting

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I am befuddled by this. I've done plenty of sorting in Js, but for some reason I'm getting strange behavior.

```
x = [{ts: "2013-09-24 14:44:22"}, {ts: "2013-09-24 14:08:26"}, {ts: "2013-09-24 17:37:42"}].sort(function(a,b) {return a.ts < b.ts;});
console.log(x); // this is sorted
```

But, when I use a longer array, the sort doesn't work. Just look at the first three objects of the second sort:

http://jsfiddle.net/HWx7p/

Any ideas?

Comment: Um... `sort` modifies the original array and returns a boolean...

Comment: It looks sorted to me.

Comment: Do this: `.sort(function(a,b) { return b.ts.localeCompare(a.ts); });`

Comment: @Kolink: `.sort()` returns the original Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparator needs to return a number, not a boolean.

A negative number if less than, `0` if equal, a positive number if greater than.

```
.sort(function(a,b) {
    if(a.ts == b.ts) return 0;
    return a.ts < b.ts ? -1 : 1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWx7p/8/

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your sort function:

```
.sort(function(a,b) {

    if(a.ts < b.ts) return -1;
    else if(a.ts > b.ts) return 1;
    return 0;

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HWx7p/6/

Answer (score 1):

Sort it as dates, that is what you want :

```
y.sort(function(a,b) { 
   return new Date(a.ts) < new Date(b.ts);
});
```

forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bHh4g/

---

Has accidently removed `console.log(y);` in the fiddle, but reinserted it will show it now sorts correct.

---

**Finally**

It turns out FireFox / Safari `Date()` doesnt like dates on the form "`2013-09-24 14:44:22`"
they need y/m/d instead :

```
y.sort(function(a,b) { 
    var d1 = a.ts.replace(/-/g,'/');
    var d2 = b.ts.replace(/-/g,'/');
    d1 = new Date(d1);
    d2 = new Date(d2);
    return (d1 < d2) ? -1 : (d1 > d2) ? 1 : 0;
});

console.log(y);
```

forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jnx4w/
works in both Chrome / FF.

Comment: So I tested it again and as before, it doesn't sort correctly, at least in Safari, [see](http://jsfiddle.net/z3QGg/). I wonder also, which overhead this produces over a simple string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: your sort function should return a signed number, not a boolean, and it looks like you want to compare dates, not strings.

For your sort function, try:

```
function(a,b){ return (new Date(a)).getTime() - (new Date(b)).getTime();}
```

Answer (score -2):

You compare string... no timestamp ;)

```
y = y.sort(function(a,b) {
    var ta = (+new Date(a.ts));
    var tb = (+new Date(b.ts));
    if (ta < tb)
        return -1;
    if (ta > tb)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/HWx7p/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by cross-compatible, but have a look at the strings.  That is a string sortable date format.  If you sort those strings as string they will sort in date order.  Always.